# How to add data inputed through combobox and add to to excel file

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

Hello Guys I'm new to VBA Excel to bear with me. This is the code I have so far. It's a combobox with three inputs 1.Part# 2. Month (Icol) 3. Amount. I want my combobox to look at column A and see if the part is located if its not I want to add that part to the bottom of the row. Everything works fine except when a new part is added not on column A. The part gets added to the bottom of the row, but the value portion does not and this must corresponded to the month the user selected ex. New part, "Current Month +1=N, 200. So add new part and add 200 to column N.

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

```
Dim iRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim iCol As String
Dim c As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim value As Long
Dim NewPart As Boolean
Set ws = Worksheets("sheet2")

Set c = ws.Range("A7:A1048576").Find(What:=Me.PartTextBox.value, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If c Is Nothing Then
'find first empty row in database
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    iRow = lastRow + 1
    NewPart = True
Else
'find row where the part is
    iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:=Me.PartTextBox.value, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    NewPart = False
End If
'check for a part number
If Trim(Me.PartTextBox.value) = "" Then
  Me.PartTextBox.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please Enter A Part Number"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.MonthComboBox.value) = "" Then
  Me.MonthComboBox.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please Enter A Month"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.AddTextBox.value) = "" Then
  Me.AddTextBox.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please Enter A Value To Add Or Substract"
  Exit Sub
End If

'copy the data to the database
'use protect and unprotect lines,
'     with your password
'     if worksheet is protected

Select Case MonthComboBox.value

    Case "Current Month"

        iCol = "C"

    Case "Current Month +1"

        iCol = "N"

    Case "Current Month +2"

        iCol = "O"

    Case "Current Month +3"

        iCol = "P"

    Case "Current Month +4"

        iCol = "Q"



End Select
value = Cells(iRow, iCol).value

If NewPart = True Then
    ws.Cells(iRow, "A").value = Me.PartTextBox.value
    ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).value = value + CLng(Me.AddTextBox.value)


End If



With ws
'  .Unprotect Password:="password"

  .Cells(iRow, iCol).value = value + CLng(Me.AddTextBox.value)

'  .Protect Password:="password"
End With




'clear the data
Me.PartTextBox.value = ""
Me.MonthComboBox.value = ""
Me.AddTextBox.value = ""
Me.PartTextBox.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Empty NameTextBox
 PartTextBox.value = ""

'Empty PhoneTextBox
 AddTextBox.value = ""

'Empty DinnerComboBox

'Fill DinnerComboBox
With MonthComboBox
     .AddItem "Current Month"
     .AddItem "Current Month +1"
     .AddItem "Current Month +2"
     .AddItem "Current Month +3"
     .AddItem "Current Month +4"

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For the line value = Cells(iRow, iCol).value you need to have whole numbers as reference not letters.

So you need to use numbers in your select statement:

```
Select Case MonthComboBox.value

Case "Current Month"

    iCol = 3

Case "Current Month +1"

    iCol = 14

Case "Current Month +2"

    iCol = 15

Case "Current Month +3"

    iCol = 16

Case "Current Month +4"

    iCol = 17


End Select
```

Comment: Sorry not sure if that's the problem. If by switching the iCol to numbers I get errors in my statements, and also I don't think this is the case because when the part is found under column A the Select Case does work. The select case does not work when a new part is added to the bottom of the row.

Comment: @INOPIAE string value is accepted by `Cells` object. Just type `?cells(1,"C").address` in immediate window

Comment: Select Case MonthComboBox.value
    
    Case "Current Month"

        iCol = Cells(3, "C").Address
   
    Case "Current Month +1"

        iCol = Cells(14, "N").Address

    Case "Current Month +2"
    
        iCol = Cells(15, "O").Address
    
    Case "Current Month +3"
    
        iCol = Cells(16, "P").Address
    
    Case "Current Month +4"
    
        iCol = Cells(17, "Q").Address

Comment: This is how I have switched it now, I get a debug error still